# How to change the Outlook 365 reading pane background color in Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11, microsoft-outlook-365

I am running `Windows 11 Enterprise 21H2`. I like the `Dark Mode` theme in most cases. But in `Outlook 365` I really prefer the `Dark Gray` office theme--except that it leaves the background color of the message reading pane **WHITE**. How can this be changed?

There's a good description of how to do this in `Win7` [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/bright-white-reading-pane-in-dark-gray-theme/2aa427df-ec4e-4d96-a3c5-3be0d5781f35), but those steps don't really exist in `Win11`. Again, *I don't want to change my windows theme nor my Outlook 365 theme*--just the background color of the Outlook 365 reading pane.

How is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like Microsoft only offers a background color change option
to the Black theme, but for some reason not to the Dark Gray theme.

You may signal the problem to Microsoft via the Feedback Hub,
which is about the most that you can do at this time.